# Installing suggested composer packages ZF2 (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: zend-framework2, pecl

when you use the zend skeleton to start your new project and composer to install packages it recommends this:

```
    "doctrine/common": "Doctrine\\Common >=2.1 for annotation features",

    "ext-intl": "ext/intl for i18n features",

    "pecl-weakref": "Implementation of weak references for Zend\\Stdlib\\CallbackHandler",

    "zendframework/zendpdf": "ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes",

    "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "ZendService\\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\\Captcha and/or Zend\\Form"
```

I could install the zendpdf, zendservice-recaptcha and doctine/common package but not the PECL ones.

I think it's a little sad that zf2 suggest the packages, but leaves users alone with, how to properly configure the composer.json.

I heard composer could also get PECL packages, but couldn't find any documentation on it.

How do I install them?

Comment: I just added this to composer.json `"doctrine/common" : ">=2.1",
                "zendframework/zendpdf": "*",
                "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "*"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install the suggested packages, modify composer.json to include them.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/common": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zendpdf": "2.*",
    "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.*"
}
```

Then run

```
php composer.phar update
```

Note: that composer installs doctrine/common by using

```
git clone http://github.com/doctrine/common
```

On Windows git needs to be in your PATH environment variable.

Regarding ext/intl, this extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0. and can be found in the ext/ folder of your php installation.[1]

To enable, uncomment (remove the semi-colon before the directive) it in php.ini

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Regarding pecl-weakref, this is also a PHP extension however this is not bundled with php and needs to be installed. More information on how to do that can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the
>   building on Windows section. [4]

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php

[2] http://php.net/manual/en/weakref.installation.php

[3] http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php

[4] http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: thx. I get now that the PECL extension and ext/intl can't be installed using composer. But still frustrated why ZF2 recommends stuff that is not even available via composer...